# Unit Testing simple login service using EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock, testcasesource

I am absolutely new to unit testing and have gone through tutorials about Mock object. I tried to test a simple login source code but unable to create the proper unit test code. Can somebody please provide some help if I wanted to test against incorrect username, correct password and correct username and incorrect password:

```
    package com.isyn.testsetup;

    public interface ApplicationUserService {

        public ApplicationUser findByUserName(String userName);
    }

    package com.isyn.testsetup;

    public class ApplicationUser {

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public ApplicationUser(String userName, String password) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;

    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    }
    package com.isyn.testsetup;

    public class LoginUser {

        private ApplicationUserService applicationUserService;

    public LoginUser(ApplicationUserService applicationUserService) {

        this.applicationUserService = applicationUserService;
    }

    public boolean validateCredentials(String userName, String password) {

        boolean validationResult = false;

        try {
        ApplicationUser applicationUser = applicationUserService.findByUserName(userName);
        if (applicationUser.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            validationResult = true;
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return validationResult;
    }
}
```

I came up with this test case for valid users:

```
package com.isyn.testsetup;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.eq;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.expect;
import static org.easymock.EasyMock.replay;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TestLogIn extends TestCase{

    private ApplicationUser applicationUser;
    private ApplicationUserService mockUserServiceObj;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockUserServiceObj = EasyMock.createMock(ApplicationUserService.class);
        applicationUser = new ApplicationUser("gooduser", "goodpassword");

    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        setup();

        expect(mockUserServiceObj.findByUserName(eq("gooduser"))).andReturn(applicationUser);
        replay(mockUserServiceObj);
        LoginUser testUser = new LoginUser(mockUserServiceObj);

        boolean checkStatus = testUser.validateCredentials("gooduser", "goodpassword");
        assertTrue(checkStatus);


        }
}
```

I wanted to check with incorrect credentials and don't know if its going to work as it shows unexpected method call!

```
Need Help!
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your test case and it runs with no problem. What is the exact error message that you are seeing?

A few notes:

1. Your test class extends TestCase, but there's no need for that in JUnit 4. Just add annotations to your test methods
2. In your test() method, you call setup(), but because you added @Before to setup(), JUnit calls it before calling each method that has @Test

Comment: Thank you for taking time for this. So since I am absolutely new to the mock testing, I wanted to know what should I do for checking test cases like 
    1. bad username, correct password
    2. correct username, bad password
    3. null username, null password
Because if I am testing it against "baduser" & "goodpassword",
it shows error:
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call ApplicationUserService.findByUserName("baduser"):
    ApplicationUserService.findByUserName("gooduser"): expected: 1, actual: 0

Comment: Also about your second concern, if I don't call setup(), it shows an error. You can try it and see.